# what is the recommended RAID level for applications by MegaRAID 9261-8i

Tags: raid, megaraid

I wanna to know which RAID level is good to set for database usage, webservers and so on when I use MegaRAID SAS 9261-8i or 9263-8i..

I will glad if help me.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. For DB itself you might want to stick with RAID10 as it gives you the best performance, but for DB transactional log RAID5/6 is fine. Moderately loaded web server could use RAID6 as storage subsystem I/O is virtually never a bottleneck (network itself typically is). Read-intensive file server is OK with RAID6, but more write-focused should benefit from RAID10. In general I'd start with tracking your current I/O metrics using something like Dell DPACK to see how many IOPS you currently use/need.